# PHP Generated Inputs and Standard DOM Inputs display differently

Tags: php, css, dom

As you can see the following produces the exact same configuration of Select:Text:Image. However whatever the HELL I do I cannot get them to display the same without different CSS which I do not want to do. I have used CSS resets, Identical CSS, removed attributes etc. Any idea what is making them act so stupidly? It is really starting to p*ss me off.

PHP Generated inputs:

```
while ( $result = mysql_fetch_array($query) ){
    echo '<div id="'.$result['id'].'"';
    echo '<select class="select"></select>'; 
    echo '<input type="text" value="'.$result['item'].'" /><input type="text"    value="'.$result['price_q'].'" /><input type="text" value="'.$result['price_p'].'" />';
    echo '<img src="images/edit.png" class="edit" />';
    echo '<img src="images/delete.png" class="delete" />';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

DOM Inputs:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="insert_db" id="insert_db">
    <select name="category" id="catselect" class="select"></select>
    <input type="text" id="item" />
    <input type="text" id="price_q" />
    <input type="text" id="price_p" />
    <input type="hidden" id="category" />
    <input type="hidden" id="sub_category" />
    <img src="images/accept.png" /><img src="images/accept.png" />
</form>
```

Regards, Phil.]

I should clarify the PHP generated inputs seem to have negative margins by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the encoding and the text editor used in saving file, it is possible that the php rendered version is not generating any white-space while the straight HTML version is generating white-space via line-breaks and tabs. What happens when you remove all white-space from the straight html version? Also, do you have a link to post your test for us?

Comment: God damn Dreamweaver is an A**, Whitespace was on of my thoughts so I deleted all space linebreaks. I think Dreamweaver had a different idea though! Edited in Notepad++ though, all is good! Thanks!